# Syntax for selecting messages by Jms ID

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, message-queue

What is the correct syntax for selecting messages based on their corresponding JMS ID?

Currently I use:

```
String selector = "JMSMessageID='ID:305:1:5:1:1'";
messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(getRetryQueue(), selector);
```

The above syntax works in test with a mocked broker. But towards ActiveMQ the messages are not polled.

Original code:

```
@Override
public Message readMessageFromRetryQueueByJmsId(String jmsId) throws QueueingException {
    Connection connection = null;
    Session session = null;
    MessageConsumer messageConsumer = null;
    Message message = null;
    try {
        connection = getConnectionFactory().createConnection();
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(getRetryQueue(), "JMSMessageID='"+jmsId+"'");
        message = messageConsumer.receiveNoWait();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        throw new QueueingException("Failed to read message from MessageConsumer.");
    } finally {
        try { messageConsumer.close(); } catch (Exception e) { /* NOP */ }
        try { session.close(); } catch (Exception e) { /* NOP */ }
        try { connection.close(); } catch (Exception e) { /* NOP */ }
    }
    return message;
}
```

Comment: Format of `JMSMessageID` is vendor specific. Did you try to see what the format is for ActiveMQ?

Comment: Yes it seems to be alright: http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-message-properties.html

Comment: What is all right? The document you sent does not mention the format at all. Try to consume the messages without selector at all and print the property `JMSMessageID`

Comment: The JMS ID is obtained through a queue browser that selects messages based on some criterias and then extracted with: msg.getJMSMessageID() So format should be alright. Syntax also seems to match what I have seen here: https://bitbucket.org/mirror/activemq/src/bf071376b576cb9a1d294822ba721b324070480e/activemq-unit-tests/src/test/java/org/apache/activemq/selector/SelectorTest.java

Comment: It must be something wrong with your other code. That selector is really ok (Given you have such a message id in your queue). Did you remember to start the connection before reading?

Comment: Thank you! Yes you were right, the connection was never started.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Messages were not read since the connection was never started.

Corrected code:

```
@Override
public Message readMessageFromRetryQueueByJmsId(String jmsId) throws QueueingException {
    Connection connection = null;
    Session session = null;
    MessageConsumer messageConsumer = null;
    Message message = null;
    try {
        connection = getConnectionFactory().createConnection();
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        connection.start();
        messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(getRetryQueue(), "JMSMessageID='"+jmsId+"'");
        message = messageConsumer.receiveNoWait();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        throw new QueueingException("Failed to read message from MessageConsumer.");
    } finally {
        try { connection.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
    return message;
}
```